# Missing client_id or access_token URL parameter for realtime subscriptoin

Tags: instagram

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here, but I have a client registered with the instagram API with a client and a secret token. I have a public endpoint listening for the challenge and response, and I am making a post request like:

```
curl \
-F 'client_id=<clientid>' \ 
-F 'client_secret=<clientsecret>' \
-F 'object=tag' \
-F 'aspect=media' \
-F "object_id=nofilter"  \
-F 'verify_token=myVerifyToken'    \
-F 'callback_url=http://<baseurl>/api/Instagram/PubSub/' \
   https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions
```

But I keep getting

```
{"meta":{"error_type":"OAuthParameterException","code":400,"error_message":"Missing client_id or access_token URL parameter."}}
```

When I create a get request with the same parameters though I get

```
{"meta":{"code":200},"data":[]}
```

So it didn't error out, but it also didn't subscribe to anything

Comment: I never figured out what was going on here, but it has to do with using CURL on windows. I used the same command in osx and it worked fine. Also my .NET error was because I wasn't specifying "POST" to the web client

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick follow-up on this -- on Windows you need to use double-quotes (") and not single-quotes throughout the command line. Single-quotes are just considered part of the value so the above would send 'client_id instead of client_id. With double-quotes it works.

Hope this helps,

Henrik

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error the other day, it ended up being because I was making a HttpSocket request using a malformed URL, the error message was not really indicitive of the problem. If your code shown here is a direct copy paste, I would suggest perhaps the double quotes on `"object_id=nofilter"` may be causing the problem

Comment: Ok, thanks I'll give that a shot. thanks. It isn't really a copy paste, as I was trying both in CURL and in .NET making a web client post request, so I'm not totally sure whats going on, maybe it was on their end?